# "winget install vscode" missing packages

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, winget

I am not able to list the all vscode packages available to install via winget package manager.. Please see the screen shot. This Winget version is the latest version right now.

```
C:\Users\<user>>winget search vscode
Name                                  Id                                  Version      Match
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio Code          Microsoft.VisualStudioCode          1.59.1       Moniker: vscode
VSCodium                              VSCodium.VSCodium                   1.59.1       Tag: vscode
微信开发者工具                        Tencent.wechat-devtool              1.05.2106300 Tag: vscode
Huawei QuickApp IDE                   Huawei.QuickAppIde                  11.3.2       Tag: vscode
字节跳动开发者工具                    bytedance.bytedance-devtool         3.1.3        Tag: vscode
Microsoft Visual Studio Code Insiders Microsoft.VisualStudioCode.Insiders 1.60.0       Moniker: vscode-insiders

C:\Users\<user>>winget
Windows Package Manager v1.0.11692
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Package Manager searches "Name", "Id", "Moniker", and "Tags" for a substring match unless you specify `-e`. If you are expecting other results, it is possible they were removed, or the manifest doesn't contain "vscode" in the example provided.

Edited (January 2022):
`winget show vscode --versions` will display the list of available versions.

Answer (score 0):

To download vs code via winget:

```
 winget install -e --id Microsoft.VisualStudioCode
```

and to see versions available

```
 winget show vscode --versions
```